# ¿se puede vincular woocommerce a mi página diseñada con bootstrap, o solo es para wordpress?

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap, wordpress, woocommerce

estoy desarrollando una tienda en línea, pero e gustaría utilizar el plugin de woocommerce, pero todo lo que he encontrado está hecho para wordpress, no se puede utilizar directamente en mi página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que Woocommerce es un plugin para Wordpress, la respuesta es **NO**, no puedes usar Woocommerce fuera de Wordpress, si requieres de una librería que acelere el proceso de desarrollo de un ecommerce puedes probar con Shopify, aunque, sus planes son de paga...